# Could not find logging path in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, spring-boot

I want to set my logging path so I can see the traces in the trace file currently I am doing like this 
logging.path = c:\temp\tracefile.log
but I dont see any tracefile. So could anyone suggest what is wrong with this.

Or otherwise is there any other way to get the traces. please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the following properties in your `application.properties` file:

```
logging.path=/temp/log                  # path for a logging file.
logging.file=tracefile.log              # Log file name.
logging.level.org.springframework=DEBUG # Log levels severity mapping.
```

If you use `logging.file` property, Spring writes to the specified log file. Names can be an exact location or relative to the current directory.
If you use `logging.path` property, Spring Boot creates a `spring.log` file in this specified path.

However, you **cannot** specify both the `logging.file` and `logging.path` properties together. If done, Spring Boot will ignore both.

Read more about [Common application properties](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html).

Comment: I was wondering is there any other way to get the traces instead of mentioning here in this file these lines ..is there any other way to control it externally

Comment: This is now packaged inside jar but I want to have it controlled from  outside by passing input parameters so is there any other way

Comment: can u suggest something ?

Comment: You can set logback configuration through an external file as well. There is an excellent article about logging in Spring Boot, please look at it: https://springframework.guru/using-logback-spring-boot/

Answer (score 0):

You can configure logging in application.properties file. Add this line to application.properties file:

```
logging.file=myapplication.log
```