# POST doesn't work Spring java

Tags: java, spring, rest, post

I have an web application and I'm trying to creat a simple POSt method that will have a value inside the body request:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/cachettl", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
public @ResponseBody String updateTtl(@RequestBody long ttl) {
  /////Code
}
```

My request which I call from some rest client is:

```
POST
http://localhost:8080/cachettl
Body:
{
 "ttl": 5
}
```

[image: POST]
In the response I get 403 error ***"THE TYPE OF THE RESPONSE BODY IS UNKNOWN
The server did not provide the mandatory "Content-type" header."***
Why is that happening? I mention that other GET requests are working perfectly.
Thanks!

**Edit:**
When I tried it with postman the error message I got is **"Invalid CORS request"**.

Comment: how are you calling this rest endpoint? from postman or some other client or from other program. You need to set Content-type header

Comment: I added a screenshot. I put the header and still the same issue. I use "Restlet" client

Comment: Did you try it with the spelling provided in the error message?

Comment: @DaveNewton headers are case insensitives. 403 is related to authentication.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what is spelling provider.

Comment: @JEY They're *supposed* to be, doesn't mean they always *are*. Here it looks more like the *response* is missing the header. 403 is unfortunately abused sometimes, and does not always mean an explicit authorization error.

Comment: @BD111 you have an authorization error but your client can't decode the server response because it didn't provide the content type of the response. Are you using spring boot did you add spring security as dependency ?

Comment: Yes I use spring boot and no I don't see any security dependency. Which one should I use and how? Thanks!

Comment: could you post your maven or gradle deps and your spring boot configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Spring application just doesn't know how to parse your message's body.
You should provide "header" for your POST request to tell Spring how to parse it.

"Content-type: application/json" in your case.

You can read more about http methods here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data

**Updated:**

Just in case of debug, remove useless annotations to test only POST mechanism. Also, change types of arg and return type. And try to use case-sensitive header.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/cachettl", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void updateTtl(@RequestBody String ttl) {
  System.out.println("i'm working");
}
```

Comment: I added a screenshot. I put the header and still the same issue.

Comment: Same issue :(((

Comment: @BD111 can you attach logs from your application? 
Also, you can set logger level to "debug", if no logs available

Comment: I'n using intellij and I'm not sure how to get those logs. Can you guide me please?

Comment: @BD111 - setting log level https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41564341/could-not-find-logging-path-in-intellij
Where is to find log files: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/setting-log-options.html

Answer (score 0):

Since the error is about the response type, you should consider adding a `produces` attribute, i.e :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/cachettl", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

Since you are also consuming JSON, adding a `consumes` attribute won't hurt either :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/cachettl", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, still the same issue :(

Answer (score 0):

The error message is slightly misleading. Your server code is not being hit due an authentication error.

Since you say `spring-security` is not in play then I suspect you're being bounced by a CORS violation maybe due to a request method restriction. The response body generated by this failure (if any at all) is automatic and will not be of the `application/json` type hence the client failure. I suspect if you hit the endpoint with something that doesn't care for CORS such as `curl` then it will work.

Does your browser REST client allow you to introspect the CORS preflight requests to see what it's asking for?

Comment: I think you are right. When I tried it with postman I got an error message "Invalid CORS request". About your question, I don't know. How can I check it? Is there any option to fix it trough spring configurations/dependency? Thanks!

Comment: OK I succeeded with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38778083/postman-resolving-invalid-cors-request-for-a-post-request , but I get a strange value inside the parameter that my function gets (ttl) somthing with WebKitFormBoundary and a lot of random chars, what is it and how I get my real value?. In addition, if I'll call not trough some rest client it will work?